# Strange reputation values

Tags: support, reputation

There is a [user on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3265284/hg8?tab=profile) who has just two posts with only one net +1 and yet total rep of 64!

Is this a bug in Stack Overflow?

[image: snip from profile]

Comment: Look at his [reputation tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3265284/hg8?tab=reputation). The extra reputation is from suggested edits.

Comment: In this instance the reason was edits, but the same could [also](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) be done through upvotes and downvotes cancelling too. 1 (original reputation) + 5 (upvote to question) + 2 (accept an answer) = 8. The remaining 56 could be due to, for instance, +70 (7x answer upvotes) -14 (7x answer downvotes), or + 40 (4x answer upvotes) - 8 (4x answer downvotes) + 40 (8x question upvotes) - 16 (8x question downvotes), etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Behold: [lots and lots of edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3265284/hg8?tab=reputation)

#### See also: [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: I'm doing some edits too, so why I could not gain reputations too?

Comment: @sємsєм It's for approved _suggested_ edits.  Users over 2k rep don't need to go through the suggested edit approval.  They just edit immediately.

Comment: @ sємsєм:- now you are not kid any more on SO(you have more than 2K rep), you become big bro. thats why, you are not earn for edit

Comment: Ok well I got it from the second resource. Thank you

Comment: @Piyush :) :) :)