# Strange behavior in Teams reputation change, is this a bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, stack-overflow-for-teams

I spotted strange behavior when reading questions in Teams. During the first time I entered Teams page, it showed correct Teams reputation (currently in 1 rep because I was just get started):

[image: Original rep]

When someone upvoted one of my existing post in the public/main SO site (approx. 3 minutes after entering Teams for first time), it suddenly displayed public site reputation instead (at this time it is around 15K rep):

[image]

However, after I navigated to another Teams question, the reputation count correctly displayed 1 rep again. Other aspects of Teams seem did not affected.

What kind of problem occurred so that the reputation of Teams overlapped with reputation from main SO site for a while until redirected to another page? Is this a bug or just by design?

**Note:** [This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320377/strange-behavior-in-reputation-system) and [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291834/strange-reputation-values) does not apply because this behavior only exists in Teams. Also this behavior is surprising me because [reputation in Teams should be separated from the public/main SO site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369596/will-the-reputation-in-so-teams-be-merged-to-main-profile).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We don't actually broadcast rep updates on channels, because of environment isolation etc (web-socket broadcasts only currently participate on the public Q+A). What is *actually* happening is that our header code, *when on a channel*, is still subscribing to the *outer site's* rep updates; you got a rep update *on Stack Overflow*, and your header bar (wrongly) updated itself with that.

I'll see if we can stop it from doing that!